# Ubuntu programs' compatibility with Linux Mint

Tags: ubuntu, compatibility, linux-mint

Are all of the programs that can be run on Ubuntu able to run on Linux Mint? I'm thinking of switching (Ubuntu to Mint), but there are a lot of programs (command line mostly) that I'd like to be able to use on Mint.

I believe Mint is based on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general using 'ubuntu' repositories is not a good idea unless you're certain that the version of mint and ubuntu are the same - you MIGHT be able to get away with limited PPAs.

You should for most part be able to run individual programmes as long as all dependancies are met - so the safest way to do it is to install the programme from individual deb archives (with dpkg), install its dependancies, and test before you do anything. In general as long as they use the same version of libc (crucial!) and all dependencies are met, you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Any FOSS programs that don't work can be recompiled. For ISV programs, consult the ISV in question.